# What causes my CSS not to be loaded by my HTML file?

Tags: html, css

All seems correct, but my CSS does not get loaded. It appears in the console on devTools (using chrome) but no CSS actually happens.

- Have been through the numerous questions about this but no answers there provided a solution.
- Have disabled the cache in devTools, no change, re-enabled it no change.
- Have triple checked the spelling of my file names.
- Moved the file to the same directory
- Tried adding type="text/css" - no change.

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Army Builder</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <div id='Container'>
    <div id="unitList">Unit List
    <ul id="list" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="roster">Army Roster
    <ul id="armyRoster" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

  </div>
```

the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

.Container {
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [one] 50px [two] 50px [rowEnd];
  grid-template-columns: [one] 150px [two] 300px [three] 150px [end];
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.unitList {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: one / two;
  grid-row: one / rowEnd;
}

.roster {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: three / end;
  grid-row: one / rowEnd;
}
```

I am fairly certain it must be a simply error, but my eyes can't see it ?

Comment: Please excuse the weird title, stack had some serious issues with me giving it a simple descriptive title.

Comment: What about starting from adding `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `ids` in your HTML but using `class` selectors in your CSS. Change your CSS to:

```
#Container {
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [one] 50px [two] 50px [rowEnd];
  grid-template-columns: [one] 150px [two] 300px [three] 150px [end];
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#unitList {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: one / two;
  grid-row: one / rowEnd;
}

#roster {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: three / end;
  grid-row: one / rowEnd;
}
```

Alternatively, you can change your HTML to use classes instead of ids:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Army Builder</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <div class='Container'>
    <div class="unitList">Unit List
    <ul id="list" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="roster">Army Roster
    <ul id="armyRoster" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: Could also replace "id" with "class" in the HTML instead

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in you css.

In Html you are writing id which need to define in css as `#` and class as `.`